# Flutter Desktop MacOS unable to create a directory outside of project folder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a directory outside of the project directory on MacOS Pro Big Sur V11.6 through a Flutter desktop app. I am using `directory.createSync(recursive: true);` of `dart:io` to do it. But that line of code caused an exception: `FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = '/Users/test/flutter_conductor_checkouts' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1))`

`directory` is `LocalDirectory (LocalDirectory: '/Users/test/flutter_conductor_checkouts'`. I changed the Security & Privacy of my Mac to allow Full Disk Access to VScode and Terminal, but the error still persists.

Is there a way to create a directory with a Flutter desktop app outside of the project directory on MacOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was the issue:

The app was sandboxed by default. It's shelling out the app which makes it impossible to create a directory outside of the app. I removed all `com.apple.security.app-sandbox` from the entitlements file in the macOS build folder.

And that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
com.apple.security.app-sandbox
```

The line above just fine for debugging and not recommend for releasing mode